# Accessing outer param inside inner map for a dynamically generated array of elements

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to return an array of elements inside a JSX template from a nested object like so:

```
<Menu
    id="menu-locations"
    anchorEl={this.state.anchorElLocationsMenu}
    anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: 'top',
        horizontal: 'right',
    }}
    keepMounted
    transformOrigin={{
        vertical: 'top',
        horizontal: 'right',
    }}
    open={Boolean(this.state.anchorElLocationsMenu)}
    onClose={handleClose}
>
    {[Object.keys(this.state?.available).map(region =>

        <ListSubheader key={region}>{region}</ListSubheader>,
        Object.keys(this.state?.available?.[region]).map(logicalRegion =>
            <MenuItem key={logicalRegion} onClick={handleLogout}>{logicalRegion}</MenuItem>
        )
    )]}

</Menu>
```

I am getting an issue when I try to access the outer `region` param from the inner loop, saying it cannot be found.

[image]

What is the correct syntax here please?

EDIT

I have tried using a fragment approach like so

```
    {[Object.keys(this.state?.available).map(region =>
    <React.Fragment>
      <ListSubheader key={region}>{region}</ListSubheader>
      Object.keys(this.state?.available?.[region]).map(logicalRegion =>
          <MenuItem key={logicalRegion} onClick={handleLogout}>{logicalRegion}</MenuItem>
      )
    </React.Fragment>
  )]}
```

But am not getting much further, its still complaining

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use more diverse variable names than just "region" for everything.

You have a `region` variable on the first line:

```
.map(region =>
```

Then two line later you have another function with a variable named `region`:

```
.map(region =>
```

Which shadows the first.  So when you do this:

```
<MenuItem key={region} onClick={handleLogout}>{region}</MenuItem>
```

Which "region" does each use refer to?  How should the language know the difference?

Semantically/structurally, is your data really an array of "regions" which each contain "regions"?  If not, rename the variables to something more appropriate for the data structure.  If they are "regions within regions", change the names to reflect that.  Maybe something like `outerRegion` and `innerRegion`?

Either way, the overall point is that if you want more than one variable in scope then you need more than one variable name in your code.

---

**Edit:** This function syntax makes little sense to me:

```
region =>
  <ListSubheader key={region}>{region}</ListSubheader>,
  Object.keys(this.state?.available?.[region]).map(/*...*/)
```

What is the intent of separating two elements with a comma?  From the error it sounds like the arrow function and the comma have an unexpected precedence for you, resulting in this:

```
(region => <ListSubheader key={region}>{region}</ListSubheader>),
Object.keys(this.state?.available?.[region]).map(/*...*/)
```

Since the `region` variable is contained within the function, it's not visible outside of that function expression.

If the intent was for the function to output both the element and the result of the inner call to `.map()` then surround them in one containing element.  For example, if JSX fragment syntax is available to you:

```
region =>
  <>
    <ListSubheader key={region}>{region}</ListSubheader>
    Object.keys(this.state?.available?.[region]).map(/*...*/)
  </>
```

Otherwise, React provides an explicit fragment:

```
region =>
  <React.Fragment>
    <ListSubheader key={region}>{region}</ListSubheader>
    Object.keys(this.state?.available?.[region]).map(/*...*/)
  </React.Fragment>
```

Or, if you wanted an actual enclosing element in the resulting DOM, you can use a simple `<div>`:

```
region =>
  <div>
    <ListSubheader key={region}>{region}</ListSubheader>
    Object.keys(this.state?.available?.[region]).map(/*...*/)
  </div>
```

**Edit:** Also, calls to code (like `Object.keys` within JSX need to be in curly braces:

```
region =>
  <React.Fragment>
    <ListSubheader key={region}>{region}</ListSubheader>
    {Object.keys(this.state?.available?.[region]).map(/*...*/)}
  </React.Fragment>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this doesnt solve my problem, I have updated my original snippet with the different param named now. Still same error

Comment: @mindparse: What specifically is the error and which specific line of code produces it?

Comment: See edited question with screengrab

Comment: @mindparse: I've updated the answer.  The syntax issue is the comma operator, which isn't doing what you may have expected it to do.

Comment: Thanks again, I have just updated my code snippet with the fact I am trying to wrap this in another element (using MUI components). I have tried the fragment approach but still hitting issues,

Comment: @mindparse: You put the fragment in the wrong place.  It should be *inside* the callback function of the outer `.map()`.  Look at what that function is doing... You're trying to separate two elements of output by a comma.  That's not how that works.  Remove that comma and wrap the two elements of output in a fragment or element.

Comment: I already tried that but got some different errors, see updated code

Comment: @mindparse: I should have caught that.  Code mixed in to JSX needs to be in curly braces.  Surround the call to `Object.keys(/*...*/)` in curly braces.

Comment: perfect thanks, working as expected although had to change from fragment to div as the MUI Menu doesnt accept fragments as children! Thanks again for your help and patience